# How to draw simple rect with cocos2d-x v3.0

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

In cocos2d-x 3.0 dont work ccDrawSolidRect. 3.0 api have class Rect, but i cant find documentation about it. How to draw simple color rect with cocos2d-x 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `void drawRect( Point origin, Point destination );` declared in **CCDrawingPrimitives**.

Call this method inside draw() method of any subclass of CCNode like:

```
void TestNode::draw() {
    drawRect(Point::Point(10,10), Point::Point(40,40));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
DrawPrimitives::drawRect(const cocos2d::Point origin, const cocos2d::Point destination);
```

Comment: This has been deprecated, is there a newer equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this code snippet:

```
auto rectNode = DrawNode::create();
Vec2 rectangle[4];
rectangle[0] = Vec2(-50, -50);
rectangle[1] = Vec2(50, -50);
rectangle[2] = Vec2(50, 50);
rectangle[3] = Vec2(-50, 50);

Color4F white(1, 1, 1, 1);
rectNode->drawPolygon(rectangle, 4, white, 1, white);
this->addChild(rectNode);
```

Reference: [cocso2d-x forum](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-to-draw-rect-in-node/16538)