# Drawing Rectangle in Cocos2dx

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am having trouble drawing a basic white rectangle using the Cocos2dx library in the iOS environment. I have looked at a couple of other implementations for guidance.

http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/draw-rectangle-with-drawrect-in-cocos2dx-not-working/14836/3

[Cocos2d-x: How can I draw a resizing rectangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29062923/cocos2d-x-how-can-i-draw-a-resizing-rectangle)

It basically looks like I need to use the class method of DrawNode::create() to make the node, then establish the vertices like in openGL, then draw it with the DrawNode->drawPolygon method and add the child node to the scene with the addChild method of the cocos2d::Layer subclass.

Here is my code.

```
bool JFScene::init()
{
    if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    auto visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();


    auto closeItem = MenuItemImage::create(
                                       "CloseNormal.png",
                                       "CloseSelected.png",
                                           CC_CALLBACK_1(JFScene::menuCloseCallback, this));


    closeItem->setScale(2.0);
    closeItem->setPosition(Vec2(origin.x + visibleSize.width - closeItem->getContentSize().width/2 ,
                            origin.y + closeItem->getContentSize().height/2));


    auto menu = Menu::create(closeItem, NULL);
    menu->setPosition(Vec2::ZERO);
    this->addChild(menu, 1);

    auto CButton = Sprite::create("CButton.png");
    CButton->setPosition(
    Point(visibleSize.width / 2 + origin.x, visibleSize.height / 2 + origin.y)
);
    this->addChild(CButton, 1);



    auto rectNode = DrawNode::create();
    Vec2 vertices[4] = {
        Vec2(-50, -50),
        Vec2(50, -50),
        Vec2(50, 50),
        Vec2(-50, 50)
    };

    rectNode->drawPolygon(vertices, 4, Color4F::WHITE, 1, Color4F::WHITE);
    this->addChild(rectNode);

    return true;
 }
```

The odd thing is that the CButton Node appears to render when I run it on my iPhone 5s as well as the close item that was included in the default file, but the white rectangle I am trying to draw does not render. Any ideas why?

Comment: I had to use    Vec2(origin.x, origin.y),
        Vec2(origin.x + visibleSize.width, origin.y),
        Vec2(origin.x + visibleSize.width, origin.y + visibleSize.height / 3),
        Vec2(origin.x, origin.y + visibleSize.height / 3)
and it worked

Answer (score 4):

You want to draw a rectangle... Look at this code snippet:

```
auto rectNode = DrawNode::create();
Vec2 rectangle[4];
rectangle[0] = Vec2(-50, -50);
rectangle[1] = Vec2(50, -50);
rectangle[2] = Vec2(50, 50);
rectangle[3] = Vec2(-50, 50);

Color4F white(1, 1, 1, 1);
rectNode->drawPolygon(rectangle, 4, white, 1, white);
this->addChild(rectNode);
```

I hope it works for you.

Reference: [cocso2d-x forum](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-to-draw-rect-in-node/16538)

---

Besides, I recommend you take a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431922/how-to-draw-simple-rect-with-cocos2d-x-v3-0) if you didn't.